# speener event in Custom Adapter For Listview Row Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android

I have done a custom adapter with `Getview` method for a custom `Row` in `ListView` and it works fine. I have four `textviews` and one spinner in my `Row`.
I want to fire the `itemSelect` event for the items of the spinner.
But the event fires every time I scroll! (so as `Getview` method)..
How can I fix it please?

Comment: corrected some spellings and formats

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecyclerView` which is more dynamic and handles `Spinners`, `CheckBox`, `Radio Buttons` etc in much better way than `ListView`.

**Useful Links**

http://andraskindler.com/blog/2014/migrating-to-recyclerview-from-listview/